# How to identify whether something is in linkage disequilibrium?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, human-genetics, genetic-linkage

[image]

If the following loci indicated the presence of an SNP in flu strains, is Locus 2 and Locus 3, which are located 10 bp apart in linkage disequilibrium?

"When alleles and molecular
markers are associated with each other at a frequency that
is significantly higher than expected by random chance, they
are said to exhibit linkage disequilibrium" Brooker's Genetics

Both loci seem to be linked, but how do I determine if it is significant enough to be considered in disequilibrium or not.

Answer (score 2):

As per the definition you gave, you check whether there is a statistical association between the two. If knowing when allele is present at a locus does not affect the probability of finding a given allele at the other locus, then they are independent (there is no association). Otherwise, there is an association and hence the two loci are in linkage disequilirium.

See [wikipedia > Linakge disequilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_disequilibrium) for more info.